# Get updated data from partial view editorfor and pass to controller

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller

I've been working on this for hours. I have a partial view that looks like below

**_Partial.cshtml**

```
@model project.Jobs
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Jobs"))
{
<tr id="jobrow">
<td>
    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => modelItem.JobId)
    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "" } })
</td>
<td>
    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.FlatRate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "", type = "number", min = "0.00" } })
</td>
<td>
    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.StandardHour, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "", type = "number", min = "0.00" } })
</td>
<td>
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Click Me", "AddRepairOrderJobs", "RepairOrderWizard", Model, new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter, UpdateTargetId = "rodetailrowdata", HttpMethod = "POST" })

</td>
</tr>
}
```

this is where i render the partial view

**Main View.cshtml**

```
 @model project.MainViewModel
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <table id="mygrid" class="table">
   <thead>
       <tr>
           <th>Description</th>
           <th>Flat Rate</th>
           <th>Standart Time</th>
           <th>Charge To</th>
           <th></th>
       </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody id="rodetailrowdata">
       @foreach (var item in Model.MainViewModel.Jobs)
       {
            @Html.Partial("_Partial", item)
       }
   </tbody>
   </table>
```

using the action method below, i can pass the existing data from editorfor tags from the partial view to the controller using the ajax.actionlink above

**Controller.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult AddRepairOrderJobs(Jobs job)
    {
        var x = new OtherModel(){
            JobId = job.JobId,
            Name = job.Description,
            SelectedRate = job.FlatRate
            StandardHour = job.StandardHour
        }
        return PartialView("_HeaderDetailList", x);
    }
```

Now, what i want to do is when i modify the values of editorfor, i get the updated data from **_Partial.cshtml** instead of the old ones when i click the actionlink, but i can't get this to work.
How can i do this without doing some 'hack job' as much as possible?

Edit: I've added the action method for loading the jobs list

```
public ActionResult NewRecord()
    {
        var add= new MainViewModel()
        {
            //other data,
            Jobs = jobrepository.GetAllJobs()
        };
        return View(add);
    }
```

Comment: Did you try using a `@for` instead of `@foreach`?

Comment: @Rafalon what difference would that make? I'm new to mvc.

Comment: I'm unsure for partial views, but *indexing*. In a loop, having `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Items[i].PropA)` allows it to be returned when `@Html.EditorFor(m => item.PropA)` don't (you may want to inspect the generated html for both of those to understand why)

Comment: i'll give it a try, be back in a minute

Comment: @Rafalon applied your suggestion but the actionlink still sends the old model data instead of the edited ones

Comment: Cause you used Ajax.ActionLink, it generated a fixed URL with the old model data. So whenever you change data, it will not be updated. You can inspect "Click me" to see more details.

Comment: @Tomato32 i changed my "Click me" button from an Ajax.ActionLink to ajax post using an anchor tag click event. Now i am getting the updated viewmodel data except the data from the partial view. Big help anyway. Thank you.

Comment: @onhax: Well played, my friend :d

Comment: @Tomato32 i solved my problem using your tip. I just needed to put the Jobs model and loop thru it in the main view instead of the partial view, then pass my viewmodel as the parameter instead of the jobs. Now i am getting everything including the updated Jobs data. Big thanks.

Comment: Did this before but with the ajax.actionlink, which didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using @Tomato32's tip. I just needed to put the Jobs model and loop thru it in the main view instead of the partial view, then pass my viewmodel as the parameter instead of the jobs model. Now i am getting everything including the updated Jobs data. I can include the code if anyone needs it.

Comment: Good solution. You're so great, my friend :D